# Getting "No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future..." exception in Scala Play application

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying a web application with Scala Play 2, Slick 3 and PostgreSQL. My purpose to return JSON from controller.

These are the Dependencies -

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.0.1",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.0.1",
    specs2 % Test
)
```

This is one of my Model -

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json.Json
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class User (id: String, name: String)

class UserModel (tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
    def id = column[String]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
    def email = column[String]("EMAIL")

    def * = (id, email) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply _)
}

object Users extends ModelInit {
    lazy val users = TableQuery[UserModel]
    implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]

    def all = {
        db.run(users.result)
    }
}
```

This is my Controller -

```
package controllers

import models.Users
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {
    def index = Action {
        val users = Users.all
        val json = Json.toJson(users)
        println(json)
        Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting following exception-

```
No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[models.UserModel#TableElementType]]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

   class Application extends Controller {
8       def index = Action {
9           val users = Users.all
10          val json = Json.toJson(users) 
11          println(json)
12          Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
13      }
14}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this :

```
class Application extends Controller {
    def index = Action {
        val users = Users.all
        users.map(js => println(Json.toJson(js))) // this will give you Future[Unit] but instead of printing you can simply get Future[Json], i.e you can map one future into another future.
        Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
}
```

or

You can do a await on you future (Not recommended) and then serialize it.

```
import concurrent.duration._
val users = Await.result(Users.all,5.seconds)
val json = Json.toJson(users)
println(json)
```

PS: I have not tested it but that seems to be the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried **users.map(users => println(Json.toJson(_)))**. Now getting **missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => Json.toJson(x$1))**

Comment: I tried first solution and again getting **No Json serializer found for type Seq[models.UserModel#TableElementType]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.**

Comment: @Ronnie : you need to define implicit Format, for Seq[UserModel] something like implicit fmt = Format[Seq[UserModel]] ,like you defined for UserModel

Comment: I added **implicit val userFormat = Json.format[UserModel]** in Model. Now facing **No unapply or unapplySeq function found** error.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to serialize Future (fancy callbacks). Future indicates data that will be awailable soon but now it's not. You can transform contents of futures however you want using `map` or `flatMap`(if it's nested, google monads for more details).

So to fix it.

```
    def index = Action {
      val users = Users.all
      val json = Json.toJson(users)
        json.map{ actualJson=>
        //do something fancy
      }
      Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
```

Although that code is blocking your thread. I suggest using `Action.async` which is asynchronous version of Action. It's pretty similar but it requires you to return `Future[Result]`. Which is pretty simple.

```
    def index = Action.async {
      val users = Users.all
      val json = Json.toJson(users)
        json.map{ actualJson =>
        //do something fancy
        println(actualJson)
        Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving Json formatter to controller solved the issue.

My current Model -

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json.Json
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import scala.concurrent.Future

case class User(id: String, name: String)

object Users extends ModelInit {
    class UserModel(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
        def id = column[String]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
        def email = column[String]("EMAIL")
        def * = (id, email) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
    }

    lazy val users = TableQuery[UserModel]

    def all = {
        db.run(users.result)
    }

    def create(user: User): Future[Int] = {
        db.run(users += user)
    }

    def getById(name: String) = {
        val selectQuery = users.map(_.id)
        val selectAction = selectQuery.result
        db.run(selectAction)
   }
}
```

And current Controller -

```
package controllers

import models.Users
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.libs.json._

class Application extends Controller {
    def index = Action {
        implicit val userFormat = Json.format[UserModel]
        Users.all.map(user => println(Json.toJson(user)))
        Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using typesafe-activator play scala + slick and was having same issue. If JSON automated mapping is using companion objects, which i'm not actually sure about, makes sense why it cant find the formatter. moving formatter to controller like ASDF said and fixed the issue for now but i feel like it would be nicer to have in model file still

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html#mapped-tables